# jQuery 1.7 working differently in IE8 and IE9?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I thought jQuery was supposed to resolve cross browser issues. Anyway I have some code that works just fine in IE9, Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8. All I am tryon to do is load a select tag with options. I have the following select tag on the page:

```
 <select id="Select0"></select>
```

And the jQuery (1.7):

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
$.ajax({ 
       type: "POST", 
       url: "myPage.aspx/MyWebMethod", 
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
       data: "{}", 
       dataType: "json", 
       success: function (states) { 
           var jsonCodes = JSON.parse(states.d); 
           for (var i in jsonCodes) { 
               $("#Select0").append(new Option(jsonCodes[i].regionname, jsonCodes[i].region_id)); 
           } 
       } 
   });
```

I need this to work in IE8 also or find another way to code it that will work in all browsers. 
Thanks

Comment: The only way to benefit from jQuery is to use jQuery. You have a mix of native code and jQuery. That's fine too, but then you need to know the compatibility issues.

Comment: `I thought jQuery was supposed to resolve cross browser issues` - but in your example there is not only jQuery but also `JSON` object and `for` loop that may cause the problems

Comment: Should I be using jQuery.getJSON() instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 doesn't support `JSON.parse`. jQuery of course has a solution to this issue. Try this:

```
var jsonCodes = $.parseJSON(states.d);
```

**Update:**

I can't get `$(element).append(new Option(x,y));` to work in IE8. The option gets appended with no label.  http://jsfiddle.net/7qfhg/. Try changing to this syntax http://jsfiddle.net/7qfhg/3/:

```
var sel = $("select");
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
      sel.append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
}
```

Comment: That is interesting and I will try it tomarrow when I get back to work but....   Using JSON.parse elsewhere in the code to append rows of data to an HTML Table and it works just fine in IE8. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You are correct, IE8 does support `JSON.parse`, sorry. IE7 definitely does not though.

Comment: Outside of switching to `$.parseJSON()`, I don't see anything wrong. if `$.parseJSON()` doesn't work in all browsers, ensure that your json is valid at http://jsonlint.com

Comment: This ended up bring the solution that worked in IE8. Had to change both the looping and the append like this code. It ended up having nothing to do with the json call - that worked as published.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include this:

```
var jsonCodes = JSON.parse(states.d);
```

Since jQuery will parse it for you when the `dataType` is `json`.

Comment: Why is an HTML string better than creating a DOM element directly?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about something else.

Comment: @amnotiam I'm actually wondering about this now. `new Option()` doesn't seem to be properly setting the label value in IE8. See the fiddle in my latest edit.

Comment: @KevinB: That seems to be an issue with `.appendChild()` on `select` elements in IE. I guess jQuery doesn't fix that bug. They would need to have `.append()` do `elem.options[elem.options.length] = new_option` or something similar.